# How do I change the coordinate system in Compose.jl?

Tags: julia

I am using [Compose.jl](http://composejl.org/), and by default it seems that `(0,0)` corresponds to the top left corner of the image.  Is there any way to change the coordinate system within a piece of code such that `(0,0)` is instead the bottom left corner of the image, and increasing the `y` value moves up, not down?

Answer (score 2):

To set up the coordinate system use the `UnitBox`, by default the origin is top-left `(0,0)`. To move the origin to bottom-right and fix the `height` and `width` to say `|1|` try this, `UnitBox(1,1,-1,-1)`.